# Not saving unique id in different table - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model-view-controller

I have a landlord and a landlord_company model. I am trying to pass the landlord_id into the landlord_company table once a new landlord_company is created. I have a f.hidden_field in the landlord_company form, but it is not working.

landlord mode:

```
has_many :landlord_companies
```

landlord_company model:

```
belongs_to :landlord
```

landlord_company controller:

```
def new
   @landlord_company = LandlordCompany.new
end

def create
   @landlord_company = LandlordCompany.new(landlord_company_params)
   @landlord = Landlord.find(params[:landlord_id])

   respond_to do |format|
      if @landlord_company.save
         format.html { redirect_to @landlord_company, notice: 'Landlord company was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @landlord_company }
      else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @landlord_company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

landlord_company form:

```
<div class="feedback-container">
   <%= form_for @landlord_company, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class:  "new.html.erb"} do |f| %>
      <% if @landlord_company.errors.any? %>
         <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@landlord_company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this landlord_company from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% @landlord_company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
               <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
       <% end %>

       <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :llc_name, class: "general-text-label" %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :llc_name, class: "general-text-field" %>
       </div>
       <div class="field">
          <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_id, :value => params[:landlord_id] %>
       </div><br>
       <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-black btn-4x" %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </div>
```

Routes.rb:

```
resources :landlords do
   member do
      resources :landlord_companies
   end
end
```

Comment: In your create action add the line:  puts params.inspect  and show us the output of your console.  It may be that the landlord_id wasn't sent to the new action and so is nil

Comment: @bkunzi01 Here is the puts.params output.

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3F/zM/SbXO/0dCsQkTtYPh4HaDwk1f3HAJ77NpLNMw2FHMt0fXt2QxEpnoTbmSSnmQUfwmuPsrAAKl/meieDEA==", "landlord_company"=>{"llc_name"=>"2", "landlord_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"landlord_companies", "action"=>"create", "id"=>"21"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong after almost a days worth of work. I nested my resources wrong. I had them as...

```
resources :landlords do
   member do
      resources :landlord_companies
   end
end
```

...and is was messing everything up! Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Change your create action to as follows:

```
def create
   @landlord_company = Landlord.landlord_companies.new(landlord_company_params)
```

Then make sure to add the landlord_id to the whitelisted params in your "landlord_company_params" method and it will automagically handle the association for you.

Comment: I did what you said, and am now getting a NoMethodError - undefined method 'landlord_companies' for for #<Class:0x007ff9f05c59d0>

Comment: Your landlord_id is a blank value "" whereas it needs to be the primary key of the landlord.  Your new action needs to have the params[landlord_id] passed to it so it can put that value in via the hidden form field.

Comment: I added, "@landlord_company = LandlordCompany.new(params[:landlord_id])" to the new action on the landlord_companies controller. However, I am still getting a NoMethodError - undefined method `landlord_companies' for #<Class:0x007f88306a1b88> when just trying to create a new landlord_company.

Comment: yea but that's basically just saying:  @landlord_company = LandlordCompany.new()  because your landlord_id param is blank as per the params.inspection you show...you need to make sure the landlord_id param is being sent to your new action if you're going to do it that way.

Comment: Thank for all of your help, I made a mistake when nesting my resources.